# Get field from dynamically/programatically named column name with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm looking for a method to change column and field names dynamically/programatically;

**as:**

```
string iLoadProfileValue = "ColumnName";

string lastCol = DatabaseFunctions.DatabaseClient
.tbl_MeterLoadProfile
.OrderByDescending(a => a.MeterReadDate)
.FirstOrDefault(a => a.MeterID == meterID).iLoadProfileValue;
```

I'll change **iLoadProfileValue**'s value programatically.
And I would like to get that column's value to **lastCol** variable.

How can it be done?

Thanks a lot.

**Done:**

Last situation like this:
THANKS to **thepirat000** and **Dismissile**

```
string iLoadProfileValue = "MeterReadDate";
var myEntity = DatabaseFunctions.DatabaseClient.tbl_MeterLoadProfile.OrderByDescending(a => a.MeterReadDate).FirstOrDefault(a => a.MeterID == 6);

if (myEntity != null)
{
    var properties = myEntity.GetType().GetProperty(iLoadProfileValue);
    object value = properties.GetValue(myEntity);
}
```

Comment: Why you use the _i_ prefix on _iLoadProfileValue_?. Just asking.

Comment: That's a bad habit :). Starting with _i_ usally means that the variable is an int.

Comment: :) thanks for the warning, i'll notice that

Comment: Could you look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383198/get-field-from-dynamically-programatically-named-column-name-and-sum-with-ef please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use reflection to get a list of properties. Look at the GetProperties() method on System.Type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()
```

You could then use LINQ to find a property that maches the one you want:

```
var myEntity = DatabaseFunctions.DatabaseClient
    .tbl_MeterLoadProfile
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.MeterReadDate)
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.MeterID == meterID);

if(myEntity != null) {
    var properties = myEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

    // iterate through the list of public properties or query to find the one you want
    // for this example I will just get the first property, and use it to get the value:
    var firstProperty = properties.FirstOrDefault();

    // get the value, it will be an object so you might need to cast it
    object value = firstProperty.GetValue(myEntity);
}
```

As thepirat000 pointed out in the comments, if you only care about a single property you can call the method `GetProperty(string name)` instead of `GetProperties()`. This would probably be more efficient if you only care about one property, and you are not reflecting over all columns in your entity.

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond. http://prntscr.com/30ej8f I tried and got like this. How can I dinamically select values with variable?

Comment: PropertyInfo has a method called GetValue(object) which takes as its parameter the instance that you want to get the value for. I edited the post to show this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You probably don't need to get all the properties with _GetProperties()_, you can just call _GetProperty(iLoadProfileValue)_ to obtain the property.

Comment: @thepirat000 Great suggestion. If he wants to get all of the properties in a loop it probably makes sense to use GetProperties, otherwise if you only need a single one then GetProperty makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Could you look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383198/get-field-from-dynamically-programatically-named-column-name-and-sum-with-ef please?