# Get field from dynamically/programatically named column name and Sum with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, c#-5.0

Today I done it here:
[Get field from dynamically/programatically named column name with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377804/get-field-from-dynamically-programatically-named-column-name-with-entity-framewo)

I referrenced it because this question is very similiar to it.

I would like to get all int values from specific column and sum them and return the value...
I how can I do it?

**For Example:**

```
string column_name = "Col1";
int meterID = 6;
```

**As old method:** "SELECT SUM(**column_name**) FROM table_name Where MeterID = **meterID**;"

Comment: What is the "example" supposed to mean? What have you tried?

Comment: I would like to SUM a column's datas with EF. I want to specify column name with variable. That's what ı want to do. tSQL is an old example to understand. I would like to do it with EF. Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to specify column with a variable when you can use a lambda?

Comment: what's lambda? i dont have info

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class

```
public class TableName
{
    public int MeterId { get; set; }

    public int ColumnName { get; set; }
}
```

and a `DbContext`

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<TableName> TableName { get; set; }
}
```

you can produce the given query by doing

```
public int GetSum(int meterId)
{
    return context.TableName.Where(x => x.MeterId == meterId).Sum(x => x.ColumnName);
}
```

Comment: thanks for respond, but this method coming easist to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377804/get-field-from-dynamically-programatically-named-column-name-with-entity-framewo Could you give an example with this method too please?

Comment: That's not possible with Entity Framework, you cannot use reflection to create queries like that. What EF sees is the `.Where().Sum()` part, then it will translate that into SQL to query the database. An alternative would be to fall down to regular SQL queries, but then the whole purpose of EF is gone IMO.